# Modifier flags for arrows and CMD

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm building a Cocoa Keyboard Manager, but I can't understand how to correctly intercept combinations of flags where the arrows are involved.

For example I can intercept every flags combination within a switch:

```
NSUInteger flags = [theEvent modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask;

switch(flags){ 
    case: NSCommandKeyMask
         //Command pressed
    break;

    case NSCommandKeyMask|NSControlKeyMask
         //Command + Control
    break;
}
```

But I don't know how to intercept combination with arrows! 
I get that arrows use `NSNumericPadKeyMask` as mask... but if write a case like this nothing happens:

```
    case: NSCommandKeyMask|NSNumericPadKeyMask
         //Command + arrow ... It doesn't work! 
         int keycode = ... 
    break;
```

How can I deal with this problem and intercept combinations with arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a BUG or not. To intercept CMD+arrow I have to use this combination:

```
case (NSCommandKeyMask|NSFunctionKeyMask|NSNumericPadKeyMask):
```

The documentation says that the arrows produce a `NSNumericPadKeyMask`, but it says nothing about the `NSFunctionKeyMask`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrows are not modifiers -- you will find an arrow key in `[theEvent keyCode]`.

In other words, when you receive a key event, and the `keyCode` indicates that it is one of the arrow keys, then you can look at the `modifierFlags` to see what modifiers are being held down while the arrow key was pressed.

Here's an example:

```
#define keyModifierMask (NSShiftKeyMask|NSControlKeyMask|NSAlternateKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask)

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSString *chars = [theEvent characters];
    unichar aChar = [chars characterAtIndex: 0];
    if (aChar == NSUpArrowFunctionKey
        || aChar == NSDownArrowFunctionKey
        || aChar == NSLeftArrowFunctionKey
        || aChar == NSRightArrowFunctionKey) {
        NSLog(@"arrow modifiers: %lx",([theEvent modifierFlags]&keyModifierMask));
    }
    [super keyDown: theEvent];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? When I press an arrow and a modifier (like CMD) the modifier flag changes (and it doesn't report only the CMD, but CMD plus NumericPadKeyMask).
Can you add some code to explain your theory? How can I intercept arrow and CMD combination?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the show, but the docs now state that arrow keys product an `NSFunctionKeyMask`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfunctionkeymask

> The numeric keypad is generally on the right side of the keyboard. **This is also set if any of the arrow keys are pressed** (NSUpArrowFunctionKey, NSDownArrowFunctionKey, NSLeftArrowFunctionKey, and NSRightArrowFunctionKey).